# Getting "Cannot set textContent property of null" error when code is run on a remote server

Tags: javascript

I am linking to an external javascript file that will work locally on my machine in Chrome, but not on a remote server. It keeps breaking at line 27, the first textContent code. I have looked on this site for possible answers, but can't get it to work. I hoping someone on this site can spot a possible error.

Code file is attached.

Thanks.

-Shawn

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    if (pathname.indexOf('question_1') > -1) {
        var Q1 = 'As a traffic engineer, Travis works for the State DOT to identify traffic safety issues and then to determine how to mitigate the issues via engineering improvements. What types of engineering improvements might be considered to improve motorcycle safety? Select all of the correct responses.';

        var A1a = "Patching potholes";

        var A1b = "Adding/changing road signage";

        var A1c = "Placing billboards";

        var A1d = "Conducting traffic stops";

        var A1Correct = "As a traffic engineer, Travis can support the motorcycle safety mission by implementing engineering improvements that could include adding/changing road signage and/or patching potholes.";

        var A1Incorrect = "As a traffic engineer, Travis can support the motorcycle safety mission by implementing engineering improvements that could include adding/changing road signage and/or patching potholes.";

        document.querySelector('#text158 span').textContent = Q1;
        document.querySelector("#text159 span").textContent = A1a;
        document.querySelector("#text161 span").textContent = A1b;
        document.querySelector("#text163 span").textContent = A1c;
        document.querySelector("#text165 span").textContent = A1d;
        document.querySelector("#text4750 span").textContent = A1Correct;
        document.querySelector("#text4808 span").textContent = A1Incorrect;
    }
}
```

Comment: _“I hoping someone on this site can spot a possible error.”_ - the only thing we can tell you is that `document.querySelector('#text158 span')` obviously did not return the element you expected, but just null instead. We can absolutely not tell you _why_, without seeing the HTML this tries to operate on in the first place. (Please go read [ask], and [mcve].) Suggest you start by comparing the source code and/or DOM structure, to figure out why those elements might not be there. Maybe the IDs are just different, if this is dynamic content generated by some sort of CMS.

Answer (score -1):

You need to listen to `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load`.

- `load` fires when all files have downloaded (HTML/JS/CSS/Images)
- `DOMContentLoaded` fires when the page has rendered

#### Solution

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded');
  // your code here (minus the console.log above)
});
```

I suspect the reason it worked locally is because you were including your JS somewhere BELOW the elements you're referencing, and now that it's remote, you're including the JS somewhere ABOVE the elements you're referencing.

### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: Thanks AnonymousSB. I tried the DOMContentloaded and it didn't work. The issue must have something to do with how the JS is loading like you stated in your comment. I will keep working on it.

Comment: @ShawnMcCulley Can you add your html to your question?

Comment: Events, like nearly everything in Javascript, are case-sensitive.

Comment: @ShawnMcCulley Did you use `DOMContentloaded` (lowercase l), or `DOMContentLoaded` (uppercase L)? You must use the latter.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've clarified in my post about the case sensitivity, posted this answer from my mobile device and it must've slipped through the cracks.